# Save list of tuples to NPZ file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My goal is to load, change, and save a NPZ file.
The file i'm loading returns 5 different keys. 4 of those keys are of type np.array, while the last one is a list of tuples. This is an example for one of those tuples:

> (array([1967, 2929]), 0.23312236286919832, array([888.117, 387.693, 851.922, 124.948]))

I have trouble saving the npz file again, as this list of tuples can't be converted into an numpy array, which is needed for saving an NPZ file. Converting the list into an array returns the following error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (44601, 3) + inhomogeneous part.

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Here my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import load
import os

directory = '/MY_PATH/scene_info_0.1_0.7'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f_npz = os.path.join(directory,filename)
    data = load(f_npz, allow_pickle = True)
    print(type(data))
    for image_path in data['image_paths']:
        if image_path is not None:
            if 'Undistorted_SfM' in image_path:
                image_path = image_path.replace('Undistorted_SfM', 'phoenix/S6/zl548/MegaDepth_v1')
            else:
                print("Undistorted_SfM NOT IN IMAGE PATH??")
    
    data['pair_infos'] = np.asarray(data['pair_infos'])
    new_file = '/MY_PATH/npz_mess/' + filename
    np.savez(new_file, data['image_paths'], data['depth_paths'], data['intrinsics'],data['poses'],data['pair_infos'])
    print("Saved to ", new_file)
```

Comment: `data['pair_infos']` the problem list?  As loaded is it really a list?  My guess it's already an object dtype array.  You quote an error, but don't show the whole thing, the traceback that tells you (and us) exactly where it occurs.  Sometimes I wish 'close' had a 'missing traceback' option (not just a more generic debugging details complaint).

Comment: If that really is a list of tuples, you need to use `np.array(alist, dtype=object)` to make a saveable array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hpaulj notes in the comments, you want to specify a dtype of `object` here, after which your code should run fine. The below reproducer runs cleanly.

```
import numpy as np

my_tuple_list = np.array([(np.array([1967, 2929]), 0.23312236286919832, np.array([888.117, 387.693, 851.922, 124.948])),(np.array([1,2,3]),5)],dtype=object)

np.savez('file.npz',dta1=np.zeros([5,5]),dta2=my_tuple_list)
loadback = np.load('file.npz', allow_pickle=True)
np.savez('file2.npz',dta1=loadback['dta1'], dta2=loadback['dta2'])
```